# Add New Back Office Field In Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

How can i add a new field in prestashop's back office? 
Specific, i want to insert a text field in the BO: Orders->Statuses->Add New Order Status under the status name. 
Which files i have to modify in order to do that? Can anyone describes the full procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Prestashop version 1.6.1.2 and added one text field using following steps. You need to make changes in core files. You have to add field in one table in database and do some changes in class and controller file.

Here are the steps to do the same. I have adde field 'my_custom_field'.

1. Add one field in order_state table

*`ALTER TABLE {YOUR_DB_PREFIX}order_state ADD my_custom_field VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;`*

2. Change class file of order state. You need to define your field in file "classes/order/OrderState.php"

After code

*`public $deleted = 0;`*

add this code snipet

*`public $my_custom_field;`*

After code

*`'deleted' =>    array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL, 'validate' => 'isBool'),`*

add this code snipet

*`'my_custom_field' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),`*

3. open "controllers/admin/AdminStatusesController.php" file and do following changes

in function **initOrderStatutsList()**

after this code

```
'name' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Name'),
    'width' => 'auto',
    'color' => 'color'
),
```

add this code

```
'my_custom_field' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('My Custom Field'),
    'width' => 'auto',
),
```

in function **renderForm()**

after this code

```
array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => $this->l('Status name'),
    'name' => 'name',
    'lang' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'hint' => array(
        $this->l('Order status (e.g. \'Pending\').'),
        $this->l('Invalid characters: numbers and').' !<>,;?=+()@#"{}_$%:'
    )
),
```

add this code

```
array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => $this->l('My Custom field'),
    'name' => 'my_custom_field',
),
```

Do changes suggested here. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I had the same code..my mistake , i had added the field in the order_state_lang table instead of order_state and i had forgot to make my variable public in OrderState.php..Thank you my friend..

Comment: When you add in lang table you have to specify lang => true in class file.